# Displaying data horizontally using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hi I'm attempting to display data retrieved from a mysql table horizontally in an html table using php. The code below works well except for the fact that it leaves out the first record (starts at the second record) in my database. I'm sure it has something to do with the counter but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to stop doing this. If anyone can point out my error I'd really appreciate it!

```
$items = 5;
$query = "SELECT * FROM members ";

$result = mysql_query($query) 
  or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo '<table border="1">';

$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     $first_name = $row['first_name'];

           if ($i==0) {
                       echo "<tr>\n";
                      }

           echo "\t<td align=\center\">$first_name</td>\n";

           $i++;

           if ($i == $items) {

                              echo "</tr>\n";
                              $i = 0;
                              }
 }//end while loop

 if ($i > 0) {

                 for (;$i < $items; $i++) {
                      echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
                  }

              echo '</tr>';

              }//end ($i>0) if 

 echo '</table>';

 }else {

   echo 'no records found';
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_` function, and your indentation is cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and remove the 1st

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

you are calling it twice, that's why it skips 1 row in your while loop

Comment: That's it thanks! I would have marked it as the correct answer but apparently I can't after only nine minutes.

Answer (score 1):

try this simpler.

```
       $items = 5;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM members ";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 echo '<table border="1">';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        echo "<tr>";
       for ($i=0 ; $i <= $items ;$i++) {

                    echo "<td align='center'>".$first_name."</td>";
                    }
}//end while loop
     echo "</tr>";
    echo '</table>';
}else{ echo 'no records found'; }
```

Comment: @matttuman because i have removed `\n` and  `\t` .try add them again and see

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before. Try the do while loop instead. Example

```
do {

// code

 } while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); //end while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
1) remove this line of code from ur scripts
2) only use while loop code instead.

Comment: Please explain that further such that others can learn from your answer